# Getting "Address already in use" error using Unix socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

Writing the C source below using Unix local sockets I got an error about the address already in use. After having checked `man 7 Unix` for further informations I tried to create a sub-folder where executing my program (obviously modifying the `sun_path` field on the current folder) but the error was ever the same.

Is there someone able to help me?

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLEN  128

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

        struct sockaddr_un      server;
        int                                     serverfd, clientfd;
        socklen_t                       addrsize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
        char                            buff[MAXLEN], *path;

        if (argc < 2){
                printf("Error: %s [MESSAGE]\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }

        if ((serverfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
                printf("Error \"%s\" in socket()\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
        }
        puts("socket()");

        server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        path = strcpy(server.sun_path, "/home/myhome/Dropbox/Sources/C/sub");

        printf("[DEBUG]Address bound at %s\n", path);

        if ((bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, addrsize)) < 0){
                printf("Error \"%s\" in bind()\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
        }
        puts("bind()");


        if ((listen(serverfd, 1)) < 0){
                printf("Error \"%s\" in listen()\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
        }

        if ((clientfd = accept(serverfd, NULL, &addrsize)) < 0){
                printf("Error \"%s\" in accept()\n", strerror(errno));
                exit(1);
        }

        write(clientfd, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        read(clientfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

        puts(buff);

        close(clientfd);
        close(serverfd);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: The error displayed is this:
"Error "Address already in use" in bind()"

Comment: hey, DO NOT use a dropbox filesystem for AF_UNIX.  It really needs to be a local filesystem.  You can google around for why.  Here there be dragons, so until you try it on a local filesystem and reproduce it, I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: It sounds pretty strange, since the Dropbox folder is located on my filesystem.

Anyway I'm gonna try it.

Comment: is DropBox associated with the file sharing service DropBox?  https://www.dropbox.com/  or just a coincidental name?

Comment: also, are you making sure to unlink the file if it exists?  http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html

Comment: Just tried it moving the program on my home, and it doesn't even work.
I'm going to read that page.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should `unlink()` the `path` file before `bind` call. You will get this error when file exists during the `bind`. Either you should ensure to unlink/remove the file before exiting the application or you could always unlink it before bind.

Check man page of [bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind). Also, note the example given in the man page at the end.

Comment: yeah, I just saw this, too

Comment: Yes, just tried and it works.
Anyway, thanks to both and +1 to xaxxon.

Answer (score -4):

You can try to use the SO_REUSEADDR flag like so:

```
int yes = 1;
if (setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
    // error handling
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I read some stuff that while it's not strongly defined that this isn't meaningful for non network protocols.